# How to label a contour in ContourPlot with arbitrary text

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling, style, text

I want to put a label on a contour in the ContourPlot with a text, but I can not do it. I have read all questions about this issue in the slack, but I could not find an answer to it.  Let say, I want to contour plot x+y in 0 and 10 intervals of both variables, and then I choose the contour 10. Now, I want to label this contour with the text "Sommerfeld". How should I do it? this is my code:

```
ContourPlot[x + y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, Contours -> {10}, ContourShading -> False, 
ContourStyle -> {Thickness[0.006], Dashed, Red}, 
ContourLabels -> Text["Sommerfeld"]]
```

Comment: `ContourLabels` takes a function or it's True/False/Automatic. So use `ContourLabels -> (contourFunction[#3, {#1, #2}] &)` and you should define `contourFunction[c_, pos_] := Text["Sommerfeld", pos]` . Note you will get the label at both ends where x+y == 10, because you added `Contours->{10}`.

Comment: `ContourLabels -> (Rotate[
    Text["Sommerfeld", {6.6, 4}, 
     Background -> GrayLevel[0.8]], -45 Degree] &)` : This is not a general solution.

Comment: Thank you. It worked.